# brute forcing a brain puzzle

Tags: performance, algorithm, puzzle

I was given a brain puzzle from lonpos.cc as a present. I was curius of how many different solutions there were, and I quite enjoy writing algorithms and code, so I started writing an application to brute force it.

The puzzle looks like this : http://www.lonpos.cc/images/LONPOSdb.jpg / http://cdn100.iofferphoto.com/img/item/191/498/944/u2t6.jpg

It's a board of 20x14 "points". And all puzzle pieces can be flipped and turned. I wrote an application where each piece (and the puzzle) is presented like this:

```
01010
00100
01110
01110
11111
01010
```

Now my application so far is reasonably simple.

It takes the list of pieces and a blank board, pops of piece #0
flips it in every direction, and for that piece tries to place it for every x and y coordinate. If it successfully places a piece it passes a copy of the new "board" with some pieces taken to a recursive function, and tries all combinations for their pieces.

Explained in pseudocode:

```
bruteForce(Board base, List pieces) {
    for (Piece in pieces.pop, piece.pop.flip, piece.pop.flip2...) {
        int x,y = 0;
        if canplace(piece, x, y) {
            Board newBoard = base.clone();
            newBoard.placePiece(piece, x, y);
            bruteForce(newBoard, pieces);
        }
        ## increment x until x > width, then y
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to find out ways to make this quicker. Things I've thought of so far:

1. Making it solve in parallel - Implemented, now using 4 threads.
2. Sorting the pieces, and only trying to place the pieces that will fit in the x,y space we're trying to fit. (Aka if we're on the bottom row, and we only have 4 "points" from our position to the bottom, dont try the ones that are 8 high).
3. Not duplicating the board, instead using placePiece and removePiece or something like it.
4. Checking for "invalid" boards, aka if a piece is impossible to reach (boxed in completely).

Anyone have any creative ideas on how I can do this quicker? Or any way to mathematically calculate how many different combinations there are?

Comment: You could use an existing solution: http://burrtools.sourceforge.net/ The link seems to be dead as of now, but I hope it gets better soon. In the meantime, search for "burrtools". It does exactly the same as you do except it prunes unreasonable sub-solutions

Comment: very cool, seems sourceforge is having some issues, but that's what I thought of in point #4 over, trying to get rid of stuff that isn't going to fit.

Comment: This link works: http://sourceforge.net/projects/burrtools/?source=directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the [Exact Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover). You basically want to cover all fields on the board with your given pieces. I can recommend [Dancing Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links), published by Donald Knuth. In the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0011047v1.pdf) you find a clear example for the [pentomino problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) which should give you a good idea of how it works.

You basically set up a system that keeps track of all possible ways to place a specific block on the board. By placing a block, you would cover a set of positions on the field. These positions can't be used to place any other blocks. All possibilities would then be erased from the problem setting before you place another block. The dancing links allows for fast backtracking and erasing of possibilities.

Comment: That looks exactly like the "Exact cover problem" indeed! I've got code now that duplicates the board for every "step down" it takes. Looking a a profiler that's around 20% of the execution of the current code. (And 65-70% is the code to see if a board setup is valid or not). So doing these operations quickly are definitely key to success!

Comment: that's where the dancing links structure is good for: you don't need to check if your boards are valid. It just places a piece and erases all conflicting other pieces. Each step along the road you have a valid board with i pieces on it. You have a solution if i==totalNrPieces.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any obvious way to do things fast, but here are some tips that might help.

First off, if you ignore the bumps, you have a 6x4 grid to fill with 1x2 blocks. Each of the blocks has 6 positions where it can have a bump or a hole. Therefore, you're trying to find an arrangement of the blocks such that at each edge, a bump is matched with a hole. Also, you can represent the pieces much more efficiently using this information.

Next, I'd recommend trying all ways to place a block in a specific spot rather than all places to play a specific block anywhere. This will reduce the number of false trails you go down.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but I'm strugling trying to imagine how to do it in practice. Some of the pieces are really "weird", like the upper let on here : here : http://cdn100.iofferphoto.com/img/item/191/498/944/u2t6.jpg . And they cross into other pieces in such a way it's hard to simplify it.

Comment: I might be able to in my canPlace function check if the placed block produces a board that is possible to solve though. For example if it boxes one point out completely, making it impossible to reach. (Or maybe making it impossible to reach by any of the pieces thats left..). I'll definitely try some more tomorrow :)

Comment: Look closely. If you ignore bumps and holes, all of the blocks in the picture have a basic 2x1 shape.